# Angular two-way bind using hash collection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to perform a bind using the value obtain from a hash-map (basically using the value of hasmap.get(key) ) . 
The bind is used on an ng-model from a `<select>`.

Here is my plunker(at the moment an array is used, but i want to use hash-map to bind based on ng-repeat element):

https://plnkr.co/edit/CxCQ2eJXj9PUeCCVHoi6?p=preview

If what i want to do it is not possible, how can i bind so that i obtain the bind obect dinamically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the mean-time i found the solution, using a C# style hash-map

For the ones interested, see updated plunker :

Plunker[1]

```
  [1]: https://plnkr.co/edit/CxCQ2eJXj9PUeCCVHoi6?p=preview
```